# Finding the area of a trapezoid given vertices

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals, area

I encountered this problem and did not know how to solve it:

[image]

I graphed it out - making a point for each vertice. I then decided there must be a 3 because when $x=0$ then $y=3$. But, according to that logic, it should be answer c - because when $y=0$ then $x=3$. But, that is not the answer.

**Where did I go wrong, and how should I go about solving this problem when I am not given an answer key?**

Comment: I'm not sure what the problem is.  Isn't the answer actually (c)?  (Normally, we would write that $\int_{x=0}^3 (3+x)\,dx$ to make it clearer what the integrand is, but I don't think that's what the issue is here.)

Comment: In the picture, didn't you click option d)?

Comment: Yes, I did. But, why is the answer not answer d?

Comment: Well, is $3-x$ equal to $6$ when $x = 3$?  If not, then (d) is not correct.  (Remember that $(3, 6)$ represents $x = 3, y = 6$.)

Comment: But, when $y=0$ then $x$ is not equal to $-3$. Or, am I just getting majorly confused?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you look at the picture of the trapezoid in question, to find its area you are actually integrating a line segment from $(0,3)$ to $(3,6)$ in $dx$.

The slope of this is line is $(6-3)/(3-0) = 1$ and plugging in the first point yields the equation $y=x+3$. Thus we will integrate $(x+3)$.

As for the limits, you need to go $(0,3) \to (3,6)$ in $x$, so $x=0$ to $x=3$...

Comment: So I should find the two points that really include the area of the entire thing, find the  equation of that line, and then take the integral of that?

Comment: @burt that's the idea, when you integrate an area under some function...

Answer (score 2):

Well, the correct answer is c. The slope of the line that represents the upper part of the trapezoid should be $m=\frac{3}{3}=1$ (the run is $3$ and the rise is also $3$ because $6-3=3$) and the $y$-intercept of that line, $b$, is $3$. Plugging all that information into the slop-intercept form of a line $y=mx+b$ gives us:

$$
y=x+3.
$$

And to get the area under that curve, you would integrate it from $0$ to $3$:

$$
\int_{0}^{3}(x+3)\,dx.
$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation of the segment joining $ (0,3)$ to $(3,6)$ is $$y=3+x$$

You are finding the area under   $$y=3+x$$ and over the $x$-axis from $x=0$ to $x=3$

The correct choice is $(c)$

Comment: So I first find the equation of the line that the area under the line is the area of the trapezoid?

Comment: Yes, of course because that is the one which you are going to integrate.

Answer (score 0):

The area is $\int_0^3 (x+3)dx = \frac{27}{2} = 13.5$

This is the area between the curve $y = x+3$ and the $x$-axis, between $x = 0$ and $x = 3$. You are trying to calculate this area, right?